# Use of のってある in this sentence

Tags: grammar

context: A person complaining about some raunchy conduct

> 女の子同士でも羞恥心とかそういうのってあるものでしょ

Even between girls, there should be some display of shame, right?  (?)

Not Sure how to parse the long winded  "とかそういうのってあるものでしょ" section, aside from the ambiguity of のってある, it feels redundantly wordy.

Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sound as if 「のってある」 were an independent phrase, but that 「の」 is a nominalizer.

「そういうの」 = "something like that"

「って」 here functions as an informal topic marker.

Thus, 「羞恥心{しゅうちしん}とかそういうのってある」 means 「(there is/exists) something like a sense of shame」.

> "Even among girls, there certainly exists a sense of shame or something along that line, right?"

The last half is kind of redundantly wordy as you observed, but that is exactly how we chat informally -- wordy and unconcise.  The point is, though, it is not at all awkward as a spoken sentence.  You should not apply the grammar for the (formal) written language.